# How to change legend label in "theme" argument in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I am using ggplot2 ro draw error bar plot. For the legend, I want it like this:

1. inside the plot. I know function theme(legend.position) can do this.
2. use latex symbol in the legend labels with function expression.

I have read several references of constructing the legend, but still have not found what I want exactly. I can perform either 1 or 2, but can not do both in my plot.

Following is R code of the plot with the problem. Since my reputation is not enough to post an image, please copy the code into your R to see the plot. I only want to keep the label contains \beta_A and \beta_B, but not the label contains group 1 and group 2.

Any ideas? Thank you!

```
library(ggplot2); library(scales) #for alpha
varx <- rep(c("group1", "group2"), each = 3)
vary <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 2)
poi <- sample(20:30, 6)
upper <- sample(40:50, 6)
lower <- sample(1:10, 6)

dat <- data.frame(varx, vary, poi, upper, lower)
dat
  #      varx vary poi upper lower
  # 1 group1    A  29    42    10
  # 2 group1    B  21    48     9
  # 3 group1    C  26    47     8
  # 4 group2    A  30    44     4
  # 5 group2    B  27    49     6
  # 6 group2    C  24    43     7

pp <- ggplot(dat, aes(colour = varx, y = poi, x = vary)) 

limits <- aes(ymax = upper, ymin = lower)

pp  + geom_point(aes(shape=varx), position = position_dodge(0.3), size = 2) + 
  ## dodge make the lines not stack upon each other
  geom_errorbar(limits, size = 1, width = 0.15, position = position_dodge(0.3)) + 
  theme_bw() + ## Get rid of the grey background
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 60)) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 19, 18)) + 
  scale_colour_hue(labels =  c(expression(beta[A]), expression(beta[N]))) + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(rep(1.5, 4),"mm"),
        legend.justification= c(1, 0), 
        legend.position = c(1, 0.5),
        legend.key = element_blank(),## Get rid of the legend box 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill=alpha(0.0001))) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove a legend you can simply add `guides(shape=FALSE)` to your plot.  In `guides` you can decide which aesthetics should display legends.  To combine legends, make the labels the same and `ggplot` will do the rest.

```
## Use this label for both aesthetic legends
labels =  c(expression(beta[A]), expression(beta[N]))

pp  + geom_point(aes(shape=varx), position = position_dodge(0.3), size = 2) + 
  ## dodge make the lines not stack upon each other
  geom_errorbar(limits, size = 1, width = 0.15, position = position_dodge(0.3)) + 
  theme_bw() + ## Get rid of the grey background
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dotdash") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1, 60)) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 19, 18), labels=labels) +
  scale_colour_hue(labels = labels) + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(rep(1.5, 4),"mm"),
        legend.justification= c(1, 0), 
        legend.position = c(1, 0.5),
        legend.key = element_blank(),## Get rid of the legend box 
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill=alpha(0.0001))) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) # + guides(shape=FALSE) # if wanting to remove
```

[image]

Comment: Correct, I don't think there's a way to do this within the theme argument.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Solved my problem perfectly. Could I ask one more question, please? Just to make the plot looks nicer, do you have any idea on how to let the legend symbol be consistent with the symbol in the line? The symbol is triangle for the red line and dot for blue line, while in the legend, both are dots. Thank you!