# Modifying the legend colour and text in ggplot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data set contains three columns, name, value and indicator. I want to plot a bar graph with these three variables. the following is my code,

```
ggplot(data , aes(x = factor(name), y = value, color = as.factor(indicator))) + geom_bar(stat = "identity" ) + 
    scale_color_manual(values = c("lightblue", "red"), guide = guide_legend(title = "text", labels = c('A', 'B'))) +  
    xlab("xlab") + ylab("ylab") + ggtitle("title")
```

and following is the graph I got,

[image]

But the legend here is not showing the lightblue and red. Only the outline is of that colour, but inside it shows only grey. Can anybody help me in filling the legend with the similar color as the graph color. Also I want to change the 0,1 to A and B text.

Can anybody help me in doing this? Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962946/remove-grey-from-legend-in-ggplot2) might help and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31198113/how-to-change-legend-label-in-theme-argument-in-ggplot2) for changing labels

Comment: @Miha Both are not working for me. The code runs, but there is no change in the graph. Can you help me in modifying the code?

Comment: I think you want to fill the bars with color, not just color the outlines so try `fill` instead of `color`.  Then change the `name` and `labels` along with `values` using `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: @aosmith it works. Thank you. Do you want to put this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `color` aesthetic only changes the outline color of bars in *ggplot2*.  To change the color of the entire bar you'll want to use `fill` instead.

After replacing `color` with `fill` in your code, you can change the colors used along with the title and labels of the legend in `scale_fill_manual`.

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("lightblue", "red"), name = "text", labels = c('A', 'B'))
```